# Drop Down Menu Assistance

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I've had a menu built for while now and I need to update it to have a drop down off the service tab to save space. Sadly I'm not too good at drop down menus, could anyone assist me with adding this? Here is the basic layout of the menu, see the jsfiddle page for the CSS.

https://jsfiddle.net/soue5fd0/

```
<div id="menu-container">
<div style="position:fixed; top:0; right:0; color:#FFF; font-size:12px;">V. 0.772</div>
    <div id="menu">
    <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="menu-hover-underline"><a href="#about">Home</a></li>
                <li class="menu-hover-underline"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>            
                <li class="menu-hover-underline"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--  Your logo goes in this div below -->
        <div id="menu-logo">
            <a class="logo-hover" href="#home"><img id="logo"src="images/logo.png" style="border:none;" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the JS  fiddle link, dude.

Comment: Also, there is no submenu *to* drop down in the HTML.

Comment: Sorry about that, The post has been updated with the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have updated your fiddle.
Your code is very rough. Still i added a dropdown.
Here is the fiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/soue5fd0/1/

**CSS**

```
#nav .menu-hover-underline>ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    background-color:#477187;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#nav .menu-hover-underline:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav .menu-hover-underline ul li {
    color: red;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Just add this CSS and the HTML given in the fiddle to your code.

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly! Yeah the code is rough, I was planning on cleaning it up once the drop down working.

Answer (score 2):

This is how a simple drop down menu can be done only with css.
Add your links and whatever you want.

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Services
  <ul>
    <li>Web Design</li>
    <li>Web Development</li>
    <li>Illustrations</li>
  </ul></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  display: none;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
}
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Here the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8wnwnba7/